# serverless-domain-manager Cannot find module './DomainConfig'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm using serverless-doamin-manager for one of my python lambda function in aws. It was working fine but now when I deploy it using cloud formation it started giving me following error

> Error: Cannot find module './DomainConfig'

Any help would be much appreciated

SLS Debug stack info

```
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6122445Z   - D:\BuildDrops\#ProjectName-CI\20200824.1\node_modules\serverless-domain-manager\dist\index.js
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6123923Z   - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6124412Z   - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6124504Z   - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\utils\autocomplete.js
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6124666Z   - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6124931Z       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6127306Z       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:27)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6128969Z       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6131390Z       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6133797Z       at Object.<anonymous> (D:\BuildDrops\#ProjectName-CI\20200824.1\node_modules\serverless-domain-manager\dist\index.js:11:22)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6136052Z       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6138156Z       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6140044Z       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6141731Z       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6144193Z       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6145992Z       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6148327Z       at requireServicePlugin (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:26:10)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6150144Z       at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:133:20
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6151720Z       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6154400Z       at PluginManager.resolveServicePlugins (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:130:8)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6155884Z       at PluginManager.loadAllPlugins (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:117:15)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6159269Z       at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:98:35
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6162302Z       at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6165235Z   From previous event:
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6168561Z       at Serverless.init (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:96:8)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6172739Z       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:86:4)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6175618Z       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6179057Z       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6183823Z       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6185908Z       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6187160Z       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-08-24T06:20:29.6189096Z       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Environment

------------------- Your Environment Information ---------------------------

```
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4267538Z      Operating System:          win32
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4270477Z      Node Version:              14.5.0
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4272513Z      Framework Version:         1.75.1
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4274676Z      Plugin Version:            3.6.16
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4277138Z      SDK Version:               2.3.1
2020-08-24T06:47:32.4279905Z      Components Version:        2.32.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone who is searching for answer, I solved it by clearing
> node_modules directory before publishing everytime.

Use this command if you are in windows environment

```
rmdir /s /q node_modules
```

This is a known bug if you are using "serverless-doamin-manager" plugin